# How to set Dolphin selected entry active?

Tags: kde, themes, dolphin

Guys, I'm with a little problem here. This version of KDE (4.5.1 - default of Kubuntu) has a strange thing with Dolphin - the file manager. When I click on a menu entry it becomes active (blue) but when I click on the window content it goes lighter. How do i set permantely to blue? That is, how can I have the blue color even when I click on the content window? This was the default behavior on the old version of KDE (4.0x -- 4.4x)

Here is the example:

**Active:**

[image]

**Clicking on the folder content:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is because there is an option in KDE that tells it to change the color when it loses the selection. Since the list view on the left is a different part of the window than the view on the right, the color changes when you move between them. You can see the same thing in other applications, such as in the system settings lists, and more.

To change this, open up system settings (ALT+F2 -> "systemsettings", or the [K] menu -> system settings), then go to "Application appearance" and select "Colors". In the "Options" tab, uncheck the "Inactive selection changes color" setting, and click apply. You should notice that the color in the system settings list view on the left will change to "normal" coloring instantly when you apply this setting. The same setting will then apply across all KDE applications.